# Multiple VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am trying to use INDEX MATCH to return a value based on multiple criteria. Someone has helped me get to a point but I cannot find a way to add additional criteria. The formula I am working from at the minute is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$H$2:$H$2000,SMALL(IF(DATA!$K$2:$K$2000="Yes",ROW(DATA!$A$2:$A$2000)-ROW(DATA!$A$2)+1,""),ROWS(DATA!$A$2:A2))),"")
```

This returns a person's name from my list of data based on the answer to a criteria being "YES".

I need to add two more criteria to return fewer results. This will be based on a month and year, both displayed numerically in different cells, i.e. `10` and `2015`. I only want to return my index list when the other values in the row are "YES", `10` and `2015`.

Answer (score 1):

Those increments and row numbers are unnecessarily complicated if you understand what they are trying to do.

The `ROWS(DATA!$A$2:A2)` simply increments *1, 2, 3...* as you fill down. This can be simplified to `ROW(1:1)`. The `ROW(DATA!$A$2:$A$2000)-ROW(DATA!$A$2)+1` can be simplified to `ROW($1:$1999)` as long as you realize that you are returning the *position within* H2:H2000, not the actual row number on the worksheet. Note that none of the simplified referenced use either a worksheet name or a column designation. They simply are not necessary.

In addition, the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) makes quick work of conditions when you use the **15** sub-function ([SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)) with optiona **6** (ignore errors). By turning anything that doesn't match into a `#DIV/0!` error, you are left with only the rows that match.

A standard formula for XL2010 and higher:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$H$2:$H$2000, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$1999)/((DATA!$K$2:$K$2000="Yes")*(DATA!$L$2:$L$2000=10)*(DATA!$M$2:$M$2000=2015)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

A standard formula for XL2007 and earlier:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$H$2:$H$2000, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$1999)+((DATA!$K$2:$K$2000<>"Yes")+(DATA!$L$2:$L$2000<>10)+(DATA!$M$2:$M$2000<>2015))*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: This is fanatastic! Thank you so much for your help with this. It has occupied far too many hours which now feel wasted as I should of asked earlier.

Comment: Glad that worked out. Remember that those are standard formulas, not array formulas. They do not require Ctrl+Shift+Enter like the original you were using.

Comment: @AlexMoore you may complete the step by 'accept'-ing the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . It'll remove this question from the 'unanswered' list. ( :