# Index match formula with multiple criteria without array

Tags: excel-formula

How do I add multiple criteria to this index match formula, which I pulled from a previous post, here: [Use of INDEX MATCH to find absolute closest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770461/use-of-index-match-to-find-absolute-closest-value).

=INDEX(B4:B10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ABS(A4:A10-B1)=MIN(INDEX(ABS(A4:A10-B1),,)),,),0))

The formula above uses only one criteria while I need to use three [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAob6.jpg)

I'm trying to use the same formula for a sample problem. I want to match  cols B & D in table A to cols A & B in table B using the closest number in col C (table A) to output into table A, the corresponding col D from table B.

Comment: What is a previous post? If someone (like me) will pick this question by a pure chance how can he tell what was the question you actually asked?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting?  Please show an example of your data as is and what you want returned in your original post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - VLOOKUP with multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083331/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: See also [Multiple VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566549/multiple-vlookup-or-index-match/33566926#33566926).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an aversion to using Array Formulas [or if you would prefer not to for legitimate reasons, of which there are some], my recommendation is that you use a helper column to create a new unique ID.

For example, assume column A contains client Country, column B contains client State/Province, and column C contains client City. You would need all 3 to identify the geographic location of a client. So, create column D, as follows [starting in D2, and copied down]:

```
=A2&B2&C2
```

This will create a new field which shows CountryStateCity. If you want this to be displayed anywhere, you may want to add commas, as follows:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,", ",B2,", ",C2)
```

Note that CONCATENATE is effecively the same as using '&'.

Now to search and find the client name in column E, which matches the geographic location [assuming that there's only 1 per city, but this is just an example anyway], do as follows:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH("USA, Michigan, Detroit",D:D,0))
```